# BBL file withTeXlive 2010 not generating

Tags: bibtex, texniccenter

I just installed the TexLive 2010 package on Win XP and using the TexnicCenter editor. I linked the executables to the BIN directories. Compiling with `latex.exe` and with `pdflatex.exe` works well, but `BibTex.exe` (v0.99d) doesn't generates the `*.bbl` file from `*.aux`. I use the Jabref 2.6 reference editor for managing the references. On my older PC I'm using the TexLive 2008, JabRef 2.2 + TexnicCenter and everything is running OK. Can somebody help me somehow?

Comment: We would need to see the error/warning messages generated by BibTeX (from the `.blg` file) and LaTeX (`.log` file). Otherwise it is impossible to say what's wrong. You can edit your answer to add this messages.

Comment: is it a typo for `Bibtex.exe` because it is `bibtex.exe`. When you run pdflatex from within TeXnicCenter it shows you in the controll window what happens. If there is no bibtex run listed, then you didn't enable the use of bibtex for your profile.

Comment: Did you rule out TeXnicCenter? and try to run pdflatex and then bibtex from the commandline?

Comment: @Herbert: Windows isn't case-sensitive so the capitalization shouldn't matter.

Comment: ah, ok then it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it's related to [recent TeX Live versions (2009 and later?) refusing to write to arbitrary folders](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-September/027232.html) with bibtex, makeindex, etc. See if replacing `%bm` with `%tm` in the build profiles works.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot, the change from %bm to %tm in the profile solved the problem :). Daniel